# convert asp DTC control to html

Tags: html, vbscript, asp-classic

I have a web page built using classic asp and it's DTC controls, I am trying to convert the page to support modern browsers, first I have started to convert the controls, i.e. I have the following dtc control (textbox) what should be done to convert it?

```
<OBJECT id=txtStartDate style="LEFT: 0px; WIDTH: 60px; TOP: 0px; HEIGHT: 19px" height=19 
    width=60 classid="clsid:B5F0E469-DC5F-11D0-9846-0000F8027CA0">
    <PARAM NAME="_ExtentX" VALUE="1588">
    <PARAM NAME="_ExtentY" VALUE="503">
    <PARAM NAME="id" VALUE="txtStartDate">
    <PARAM NAME="ControlType" VALUE="0">
    <PARAM NAME="Lines" VALUE="3">
    <PARAM NAME="DataSource" VALUE="">
    <PARAM NAME="DataField" VALUE="">
    <PARAM NAME="Enabled" VALUE="-1">
    <PARAM NAME="Visible" VALUE="-1">
    <PARAM NAME="MaxChars" VALUE="11">
    <PARAM NAME="DisplayWidth" VALUE="10">
    <PARAM NAME="Platform" VALUE="256">
    <PARAM NAME="LocalPath" VALUE=""></OBJECT>
```

the headers of my asp page are:

```
<%@ Language=VBScript codepage=65001 %>
<% Server.ScriptTimeout = 1000 %>
<script id="DebugDirectives" runat="server" language="javascript">
<FORM name=thisForm METHOD=post>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<OBJECT RUNAT=server SCOPE="Page" PROGID=VB6Sup.CentralCRM id=CustomerInfo></OBJECT>
<OBJECT RUNAT=server SCOPE="Page" PROGID=AddressLib.Main id=Address ></OBJECT>
<META name=VI60_defaultClientScript content=VBScript>
<TITLE>HAWB Search</TITLE>
<SCRIPT ID=serverEventHandlersVBS LANGUAGE=vbscript RUNAT=Server>
```

Comment: The object looks to be some kind of VB6 rendered object. Have you checked on the providers website for a recent update for the DTC plugins?

Answer (score 0):

Hello how are you? I do not know convert, but the site [bootsnipp.com](http://bootsnipp.com/) is a forum where users share examples of forms using bootstrap. You can replace your forms by the DTC type.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Hello Glen, I try to avoid this, but in this case I am indicating a community that users share HTML forms using Bootstrap, reaching his goal which is to make modern browsers recognize the forms it.To give him the code, you need a print of the page so I could make an HTML that would reach the same end result, but being recognized in modern browsers.